# Create overview table with true false values based on rows exist in child table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with cases, and another table with notifications.

For simplicity let's say the `case` table contains

```
id   int
name nvarchar(100)
```

The `notification` table contains:

```
id               int
caseid           int
notificationtype string
```

Notification types can be either 'standard' or 'critical'.

I'd like an sql that can give me an overview for each case, and if they have any critical or standard notifications.

So a result like this:

```
CaseId  CaseName   StdNotification  CriticalNotification
1       Test case  yes              no
```

I tried this SQL:

```
select distinct case.id as CaseId,
                case.name as CaseName,
                notifications.notificationtype,
                case notifications when 'standard' then 'yes' else 'no' end as StdNotification,
                case notifications when 'critical' then 'yes' else 'no' end as CriticalNotification
from cases
    inner join notifications on Notifications.caseid = case.id
```

But this gives me duplicate rows for each combination

```
CaseId  CaseName   StdNotification  CriticalNotification
1       Test case  yes              no
1       Test case  no               yes
```

So, how do I construct a sql that wil make some kind of "sum" and only return one row for each case?

Comment: Is your table called case or cases? Both cases are bad table names...

Comment: and your query should work if `Notification types can be either 'standard' or 'critical'.` because it is working

Comment: @tinka The problem is current query return two rows instead one condense row

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it is returning single row `-- declare table
declare @case table
(id   int,
name nvarchar(100))
-- insert the data
insert into @case values (1,'case1')

-- declare table
declare @noti table
(id               int,
caseid           int,
notificationtype nvarchar(33))
-- insert the data
insert into @noti values (1,1,'standard')

-- query
select c.id,c.name,
case when n.notificationtype ='standard' then 'Yes' else 'NO' end AS stdNotification,
case when n.notificationtype ='critical' then 'Yes' else 'NO' end AS critiNotification
from 
@case c join
@noti n on c.id = n.caseid`

Comment: @tinka why not put that as an answer instead or provide a working sqlfiddle

Comment: @tinka I guess OP miss the `insert into @noti values (1,1,'critical')` for first query.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want `distinct`.  You want `group by`.  Your data structure suggests that a given case could have more than one notification, so I would go with counts using conditional aggregation:

```
select c.id as CaseId, c.name as CaseName,
       sum(case when n.notificationtype = 'Standard' then 1 else 0 end) as NumStandard,
       sum(case when n.notificationtype = 'Critical' then 1 else 0 end) as numCritical
from cases c left join
     notifications n
     on n.caseid = c.id
group by c.id, c.name;
```

You can convert these to "yes" and "no" using another `case`.

Also, note that I changed the `inner join` to a `left join`, so you'll get cases that have no notifications at all.

Comment: I just realize the posibility of multiple notifications after reading tinka comment.  :(

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. In my application where I display the rows, I just check if NumStandard or NumCretical is greather than zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.id as CaseId, 
       C.name as CaseName,
       IIF(n1.notificationtype IS null, 'no', 'yes') as StdNotification,
       IIF(n2.notificationtype IS null, 'no', 'yes') as CriticalNotification

FROM [case] C
left join notification n1
       on C.id = n1.caseid and n1.notificationtype = 'standard'
left join notification n2
       on C.id = n2.caseid and n2.notificationtype = 'critical'
```